# How linear regression can be used - explanation for grandmothers

Tags: regression, linear, intuition

Educational question.

Suppose you have to explain linear regression to your granny. She is well educated, she knows even the idea of the hypothesis testing, but before you start to tell her what regression is she asks you: "Why do I need to study a regression? How could it help me?"

The problem is to explain the goals and benefits of a linear regression without mathematical terminology (without definition of linearity, for example). Can it be done?

My variant is "Suppose we have Y and X - vectors of equal length (continuous measurements). We want to study if Y has a relationship with X. Linear regression can help us to establish properties of one particular type of a relationship".

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you should refuse to teach it if you are not already able to answer this question.

Comment: @PeterFlom I am able, I am not satisfied with my answer. Prediction and "linear" relationships do not sound really intuitive. I am always trying to say why it is useful to study a method *before* the explanation of the method, but I can not do it with the linear regression. It is easy to explain method first and then goals of the regression, but it is not so easy vice versa.

Comment: @PeterFlom in other words - how to explain simple linear regression to a grandma without using the definition of linear equation $y = ax + b + \epsilon$?

Comment: Maybe you can ask your grandma how she would draw a line that best 'fits' a cloud of points?

Comment: Linear regression is basically a fancy way of comparing means, and people understand means. Hence, I would use an explanation involving means. As in, what do people earn on average (a.k.a $y = a + \epsilon$)? But hey, maybe we should take into account different education levels. What do people in different education levels earn (a.k.a $y = a + b*edu + \epsilon$), and so forth... Describing regression in terms of the conditional expectation is quite powerful in my experience.

Comment: So granny doesn't know what linearity is, but knows what a vector is?

Comment: @fcop it sounds like visualisation technique...why we need this line? But yes, it is a good way, but it is not clear what to conclude from the best fitted line.

Comment: @coffeinjunky it is good way, but do you assume that education level is a factor? Or is it continuous?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone ordered set of objects. Easier than $y = ax + b$.

Comment: @German, Whatever suits the expositional purpose best, I would say. ;) Having said that, people often understand categorial outcomes such as educational degrees, so I would probably start there.

Comment: @German Demidov I think my long since departed grannies had some vague idea what linearity is, but no idea whatsoever what a vector is.  Maybe your grannies are the reverse.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone but it is really easy to explain what vector is. I can provide a table with weights and heights (as was stated in the answer to the question) and say that each row is a vector.

Comment: @German Demidov: you say 'visualisation technique' but doesn't 'linear' mean 'like a line' (for non-mathematicians) ? And 'like a line' is 'visual' ?

Comment: @fcop I fully agree with you about the simplicity of a visual explanation, but the benefits of this particular method is not shown in this explanation, also it is not clear "why and when" a granny should apply it.

Comment: Are you sure that knowing about hypothesis testing is a symptom of being *well*-educated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with some games: give the person you want to teach many continuous numbers which represent a group of people's weight, and ask him/her to predict next. I would say, the person is very likely to use average of all numbers for the prediction. Ask the person why. Try to plant a seed to say using mean is essentially to have a predictor: $y=\beta_0$

Now, we will go to next game: in addition to only give the person predicting target, i.e., weight, give him/her additional information: height. Apparently height is very useful, in most cases, the taller suggests heavier. But the question is: what is the predictor / formula.

You can give him/her some formula got from the regression, such as $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x$ and let the him/her to use this for prediction. I think him/her will like the idea.

When him/her ask you how did you get the formula, you can tell the whole "linear regression" story, i.e., what the $\beta_0$,$\beta_1$ represent for and how to get them.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was asking for. It is pretty intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

I have had to do this before.  I thought that comparing to a cab ride was easy.

You have a flat fee to get into the cab even if you go nowhere and then you pay a fee per mile.

Now, what if you don't know the fees but have a history of trip prices?

That was easy for people to understand since that's something that they deal with often here where I live.

Answer (score 2):

Linear regression fits a line to data:[image: Wikipedia Linear Regression]

Linear regression as estimating a conditional expectation function:

- This is immediately useful for simple forecasting. Tell me x, and I can say something about y.
- For example, forecast plant growth based upon sunlight exposure.

Linear regression as estimating causal effects:

- In some situations (eg. when variation in `x` is exogenously introduced by the researcher), linear regression can estimate causal effects.
- If sunlight exposure is randomly assigned by researchers, the regression line would estimate the causal effect of sun exposure on plant growth (i.e. the local average treatment effect).

Linear, ordinary least squares regression is the starting place for all sorts of more advanced estimation techniques. Linear regression is to data analysis as salt is to cooking. You don't *have* to add it, but it's everywhere.

Comment: good point! I will use it for sure, it is short and meaningful. But I need to explain linear regression for the granny who is doing research, and I need to explain how it can be used in the research. Fitting line tells nothing about possible benefits of using this particular method for the research...

Comment: Maybe linear regression would be anti-beneficial to granny's research. Maybe granny would benefit more from nonlinear regression? Maybe granny would benefit from constraints on parameters? From non-identity error covariance matrix, etc.  or do you already know granny's research problem, and are confident linear regression will be beneficial to her?  Or is it only a gateway drug to more sophisticated methods?

Comment: @GermanDemidov Hmm. Explaining when fitting a regression line is straight forecasting vs. when fitting a regression line estimates some causal effect may get tricky.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I am a bit confused with your proposition. I want to explain correctly how and when a granny should use a linear regression. How can it be anti-beneficial? She will be able to solve problems that can be solved with the linear regression (if i will do my job well). It is not possible to learn all the methods. A granny can be a medical doctor - she does not have time for learning sophisticated methods, she is busy with her medical stuff.

Comment: @MatthewGunn I did not think about it. We fit the same model, but does good forecasting leads to existing of causal effects? Seems that yes...

Comment: @GermanDemidov Linear regression builds a linear conditional expectation function of $y$ given $x$, that may be due to $x$ causing $y$, $y$ causing $x$, or some third factor $c$ causing both. You need more structure to know what you're estimating. In the social context, you have the issue of selection bias. Imagine you randomly assign kids to receive pre-school. Sounds like a great experiment to estimate the effects of preschool! Except that if the kids denied treatment have parents that find some other preschool, then the control group receives treatment too!! These issues get very tricky...

Comment: @MatthewGunn sorry, I do not understand the part about "estimating causal effects". Why do we need to introduce the variance in x exogenously? Can I replace these words with "simple random sampling"?

Comment: @GermanDemidov no, "estimating causal effects" is not the same as "simple random sampling." Put wages on the $y$ axis. Put education on the $x$ axis. Plot data (education, wage) data from randomly sampled individuals. Estimate a best fit line. You'll find an upwards curve. *BUT* is that due to education causing higher wages? Or is it that talented individuals choose to go to college, but it's the underlying talent, not the college education that's causing the higher wages?

Comment: @MatthewGunn argh, now I got it! Thank you. So the researcher should manually manipulate a predictor $x$ and look at the response $y$? Is it absolutely correct? Could your tricky example with wages and education be modified even for exogenously introduced predictor values? You may have forward-backward causality...

Comment: @GermanDemidov All I'm trying to say there is that: (1) in general, linear regression does not estimate causal effects but that (2) with sufficient assumptions, you do estimate a causal effect. Even exogenous variation introduced by the researcher isn't quite sufficient on its own (eg. my preschool example where control group goes out and finds treatment).

Estimating causal effects gets tricky, especially in the social context. There are things you can do to alleviate concerns, but you rarely get entirely bulletproof, absolutely unimpeachable results.

Comment: @MatthewGunn thank you! These are very good points. I will try to combine the answers from the topic and make a summary - short introduction "why and where do you need to use a linear regression".